# how to test twitter api method in application controller using cucumber -rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, cucumber, webmock

I have been trying to test/stub application method method that calls a twitter api but i am not getting any success because the method is still calling the original method.Am i missing something because i have been using cucumber and fakeweb...now i am using webmock but still not stubbing the request..

**my gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'twitter'
#### gem 'grackle'
###gem 'rack-ssl'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'simplecov', :require => false, :group => :test

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  # database_cleaner is not required, but highly recommended
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.4"
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery


  #basic configuration using the credentials
  def get_tweets search_text

    begin

    # hit the API
      TWITTER_CLIENT.client.search(search_text, :count => 10, :result_type => "recent").collect do |tweet|
        @tweets = "#{tweet.urls}"       
      end
    rescue

      @tweets = "It seems that something has went wrong,Please try after some time" if @tweets == nil

    end

  end

end
```

**my feature file**

```
Feature: Verify tweet page 
  In order to search for a hashtag
  the user will enter the details in the textbox and click on submit button


  Scenario: Land on tweet page and search for a name and verify 
   Given a user visits the tweet page
   Then the user should see "Search"
   ##user fill in Bill
   When the user fill in the textbox
   ##And the user clicks the Search button
   Given the remote service will return a valid response
   Then the user should see "http://some1.url.test"
   Then the user should see "http://some2.url.test"
   Then the user should see "http://some3.url.test"
```

**my web_steps.rb**

the code that I commented  is been tried but still when i print body I still get the error message: "It seems that something has went wrong, Please try after some time"

```
Given /^the remote service will return a valid response$/ do



  ##static file having json response containing the url that i am looking in feature file
  @canned_response = File.open("#{Rails.root}/test/responses/canned_response.json").read

 controller=ApplicationController.new
 stub_request(:get, "http://localhost:4567/tweet/user_tweet").to_return(canned_response)



###puts  Net::HTTP.get("www.example.com", '/')


  #WebMock.stub_request(:any, "http://localhost:4567").to_return(canned_response)
  # uri = URI.parse("http://www.example.com/")
  # req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
  # req['Content-Length'] = 3
  # Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) {|http|
  # http.request(req, "abc")
  # }
  # p req
  # canned_response = IO.read("#{Rails.root}/test/responses/canned_response.json")
   # {:body => canned_response, :status => 200}
   # stub_request(:any, 'http://localhost:4567').to_return do |request|
    # # p '22222222222222'
     # body = CGI::unescape(request.body)
    # # p '333333333333333'
     # code = body.match(/<CODE_NBR>(.*)<\/CODE_NBR>/)
    # # p "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
    # # p code
     # response = canned_response
     # {:body => response, :status => 200}
   # end
   # p body

end
```